# jwplayer5 proxy plugin document or tutorial

Tags: flash, actionscript, jwplayer

I want to grab video from some site like youtube, picasa with jwplayer5 plugin. I know gkplugin can do that, but it paid. So i want to ask Is there have some document or tutorial to make jwplayer 5 proxy plugin?

Comment: There are no tutorials that we are aware of that help you steal / leech videos from other content providers. We have a building plugin SDK with a readme, but it will not tell you how to make a plugin for stealing content.....